# Facebook OAUTH Server-side authentication fails

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

Following the server-side authentication proceedures defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/.

Ran this command:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxx&state=you&redirect_uri=http://lovers.net&scope=ads_management,offline_access

Which results in this:

=">http://lovers.net/?state=you&code=AQA7c30iVuCyDJzlKP8-9z_Rv7JhpnHEEfsiT5doge1TL--WSXdK9NjCl7q7_Ldovrc9SrlaOZe9VzS1pvelthA2hD72Q5aTVjFlviNPuQJ1U3LP16e7zY7lI5avSlcL1wZoOYYi5JeoOsPwe9HaeQvtfBQSYVX2WQCbo2tVFYboSq1_FNSHOpAKsaW86-1IJM#*=*

Which I turn into this:

=">https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://lovers.net&client_secret=xxxxx&code=AQA7c30iVuCyDJzlKP8-9z_Rv7JhpnHEEfsiT5doge1TL--WSXdK9NjCl7q7_Ldovrc9SrlaOZe9VzS1pvelthA2hD72Q5aTVjFlviNPuQJ1U3LP16e7zY7lI5avSlcL1wZoOYYi5JeoOsPwe9HaeQvtfBQSYVX2WQCbo2tVFYboSq1_FNSHOpAKsaW86-1IJM#*=*

Which results in this:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've specified a different value for the `redirect_uri` parameter in the call to `/oauth/access_token` as you did when you sent the user to the auth dialog - this is the case in the example you've posted in the question, so check it's not also the case in your code.

Comment: Thanks Igy, but that's not the issue.  I changed it to lovers.net to not show the real address we're using, but I missed the last usage.

Comment: Try putting a '/' at the end of the redirect URI (in both places), i think someone here said that solved a problem - the 'error validating code' means something doesn't match between the parameters passed to the oauth dialog and the parameters you're sending to exchange the code for a token

Comment: Adding the '/' at the end fixes the issue.  Thanks Igy